# What game (rpg?) is this?

Tags: game-identification

I've just found this cute and awesome picture from the web:

[image: Screenshot of a cute MEOW !]

The laptop behind seems to have a game running. I'm curious: What game is that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The game in that photo is called "Millionaire City", it is a city building game which is available on Facebook, Android and iOS.